# Loading an html template from remote site

Tags: javascript, html, import

I have a simple widget, and want to load it on different sites. I've read [this article](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/) and tried to make a solution with `AJAX` - setting response type to `document` .

Everything seems ok on first look - slider items loaded, styling is ok. But slider does not start to roll. Seems javascript does not start to run. Pervious/Next buttons also not working.

Below code describes what I've tried so far.

**Widget** - I used twig for templating, however it is not important. And that produces a carousel/slider [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AX6Gz.png).

```
<div class="slider-items-holder">
    <div class="control-btns">
        <ul><li><strong>Slider</strong></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="prev"></a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="next"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <ul>
        {% for job in jobs %}
            <li>
                <div class="job-spotlight">
                    <a href="{{ job.slug }}"><h4>{{ job.title }}<span class="job-type part-time">{{ job.type }}</span></h4></a>
                    <span><a target="_blank" href="{{ job.loc_statecode }}">
                        <i class="marker"></i> {{ job.loc_state }}</a>
                    </span>
                    <span><i class="user"></i>{{ job.company }}</span>
                    <p>{{ job.detail|striptags }} ... </p>
                    <a href="{{ job.slug }}" class="button">Apply For This Job</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

**JS**

```
function fetch_jobs_widget(selector) {
  var url = "http://localhost:9874";
  var t = "/static";
  var js_template = '<script type="text/javascript" src="'+url+'/js/script.js"></script>';
  var css_template = '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'+url+'/css/styles.css">'
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", url+t, true);

  xhr.responseType = 'document'; 
  xhr.onload = function(e) {
    container(selector).innerHTML = "";
    var doc = e.target.response;
    var widgetFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

    widgetFragment.appendChild(doc.querySelector(".my-slider")); 

    container(selector).appendChild(widgetFragment);
    container(selector).innerHTML += css_template;
    container(selector).innerHTML += js_template; 

  }

  xhr.send();
}
```

**HTML** - And I want to use that widget on that page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div class="textwidget jobs-plugin-carousel">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="widgets.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">fetch_jobs_widget('.textwidget');</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have also tried to load HTML/CSS/JS at once but I've came up with the same result.

**UPDATE**

*JS code for slider*

```
//script.js
(function () {
        var mySlider, cWrapper, ul, li;
        var current = 0;
        var timeOut = 3000;
        var intervalHandler;
        var automaticStart = true;

        init();

        function init() {
            mySlider = document.querySelector(".my-slider");
            cWrapper = document.querySelector(".my-slider > .content-wrapper");
            ul = document.getElementById("slider-items-holder");
            li = ul.querySelectorAll("li");

            if (!mySlider || !cWrapper || !ul || !li.length)
                return;

            ul.style.width = cWrapper.offsetWidth * li.length;
            ul.style.height = cWrapper.offsetHeight;

            bindEvents();
            startSlider();
        }

        function startSlider() {
            if (automaticStart)
                intervalHandler = setInterval(next, timeOut);
        }

        function next() {
            if (current + 1 >= li.length) {
                current = -1;
            }

            ul.style.marginLeft = '-' + (li[0].offsetWidth * ++current);
        }

        function prev() {
            if (current - 1 < 0) {
                current = li.length;
            }

            ul.style.marginLeft = '-' + (li[0].offsetWidth * --current);
        }

        function bindEvents() {
            mySlider.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
                clearInterval(intervalHandler);
            });

            mySlider.addEventListener('mouseout', startSlider);

            var prevBtn = document.querySelector(".my-slider > .control-btns a.prev");
            var nextBtn = document.querySelector(".my-slider > .control-btns a.next");
            if (prevBtn)
                prevBtn.addEventListener('click', prev);

            if (nextBtn)
                nextBtn.addEventListener('click', next);
        }
    })();
```

Comment: Which plugin you are using for carousel/slider. It looks like your plugin not initialize correctly. You need to reinitialize it when your html is added to DOM.

Comment: no plugin. jsut a homemade javascript -)) let me update my question with js and css codes.

Comment: You need to call your plugin's init() function when you loaded your html through ajax. Because your plugin only works for those elements that are available in DOM when init() called first time. So just call init again after you added new slider

Comment: Is the site within the same Origin? I.e. Same domain

Comment: @R.K.Saini let me try it

Comment: @XPLOT1ON no, I have set CORS in a proper way, that's not problem

Comment: @R.K.Saini do you have an idea how can i call this? I've tried with no success

Answer (score 1):

As I see your slider closely I found that you have this line

```
ul = document.getElementById("slider-items-holder");
```

which try to find an element with ID "slider-items-holder" but in your slider template you don't have this id for your ul element. So add this id to your second ul element.

**Edit**

The way you add your JavaScript file dynamically is wrong. You need to add your script to head tag to your html page like this

```
var myScript= document.createElement('script');
  myScript.type = 'text/javascript';
  myScript.src = 'http://localhost:9874/js/script.js';
(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]||document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(myScript);
```

Comment: sorry, i've changed code later. this is not issue. let me update it however. as you've written on comments slider's javascript code does not recognize the new dom elements - or my html do not recognize new dom elements.

Comment: Are you sure your script.js file loaded perfectly. Add a console.log in your init() function to check if it is loaded or not. Or you can use developer tool to check if javascript file loaded or not.

Comment: this is my point. 
when i inspect element, i can see `<script type="text/javascript" src="my_sldier_javascript">`. however it seems it is not loaded properly - `console.log(li.count)` does not log anything.